# How can my activity run on two layouts?

Tags: java, android

Basically, I have 2 xml layouts. One is for small screen size and the other is for big screen size. On my small screen size's XML layout, I really just copy exactly what I have in big screen size XML (keep everything the same such as: id names, etc.) and only change text sizes and button sizes. Then, use a condition in my activity code to call them like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (condition){
      setContentView(R.layout.bigScreenSize);
    } else{
      setContentView(R.layout.smallScreenSize);
}
```

My question is why doesn't my app crash but instead functioning normally? Is it because of having the same property Ids on both XML layouts? Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend use of configuration qualifiers to address differences like this - https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Comment: `Is it because of having the same property Ids on both XML layouts` yes - it has all you try to access. But as @JohnO'Reilly mention, you do this wrong. On Android you got mechanisms that will solve this for you - no need for `if()`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to target small and large screen sizes is not as per the recommendations from Google.

In order to optimize your ui for different screen sizes, you indeed need different layouts but they must be same identical (in terms of id's) and should only be included in different layout directories.

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

> why doesn't my app crash but instead functioning normally?

Why do you expect your app to crash? It is perfectly normal to have id's pointing to different widgets/views. As long as one does not points to two different views simultaneously. In your case only one of the two layouts (either big or small) is being used at once. So android correctly identifies which I'd refers to which view in the layout.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> why doesn't my app crash but instead functioning normally?

It is working because it's really possible to use two layouts. You can use as many layouts as possible for a single activity but not simultaneously.

> Is it because of having the same property Ids on both XML layouts?

It is not because you're referring to *same* property Ids but because you are referring to **existing** Ids that are available in both of the xml layouts.

Answer (score 1):

> why doesn't my app crash but instead functioning normally?

Because the required views ( Text/Button) are available in the xml. In other words all id's are available in both xmls.

If the id's value or any view is missing/mismatch, the app will throw error.